# Error al compilar programa en RPC

Tags: c, linux

al momento que he creado una practica escolar y utilizo punteros, me lanza el error de *Violacion de segmento* al ejecutar mi app de cliente. Utilizo ParrotOS, RPCBIND para generar cliente y server.
Anexo mi codigo cliente y mi codigo server. Cualquier ayuda les agradeceria muchisimo.

Al momento de compilar mi archivo cliente y server, estos si realizan la conexion, sin embargo, cuando quiero ver que valor de indicador recibiò el cliente es donde me aparece el error de que el puntero *indicador recibe basura, leyendo al respecto, posiblemente sea un error de acceso de memoria, pero no puedo encontrar el error
Cualquier ayuda les agradeceria muchisimo comunidad.

CLIENTE:

```
include "Matriz.h"


void
matrizprograma_1(char *host)
{
    int cX = 0; int cY = 0;
    CLIENT *clnt;
    int  *indicador = 0;
    char *checkoutclientesexistentes_1_arg;

    int  *ordenMatriz1;
    Orden  setordenmatriz_1_arg;

    int *ordenMatriz2;
    char *getordenmatriz_1_arg;

    int  *coordenadaX;
    char *sendcoordenadaxtoclient_1_arg;
    
    int  *coordenadaY;
    char *sendcoordenadaytoclient_1_arg;

    void  *result_6;
    Producto  putresultadomatrizresultante_1_arg;

#ifndef DEBUG
    clnt = clnt_create (host, MatrizPrograma, MatrizVersion, "udp");
    if (clnt == NULL) {
        clnt_pcreateerror (host);
        exit (1);
    }
#endif  /* DEBUG */

    indicador = checkoutclientesexistentes_1((void*)&checkoutclientesexistentes_1_arg, clnt);
    if (indicador == (int *) NULL) {
        clnt_perror (clnt, "call failed");
    }

    if (indicador == 0) {
        printf("\nServer: Usted es el primer cliente\n");
        printf("Ingrese la orden de la matriz al server: ");
        scanf("%d", &setordenmatriz_1_arg.ordenMatriz);

        ordenMatriz1 = setordenmatriz_1(&setordenmatriz_1_arg, clnt);
        if (ordenMatriz1 == (int *) NULL) {
            clnt_perror (clnt, "call failed");
        }
    }else {
        printf("\nSERVER: Ya existe un primer cliente: %d.\n", indicador);
        
        ordenMatriz2 = getordenmatriz_1((void*)&getordenmatriz_1_arg, clnt);
        if (ordenMatriz2 == (int *) NULL) {
            clnt_perror (clnt, "call failed");
        }
        printf("El orden de las matrices a manejar: %d", ordenMatriz2);
    }

    int orden = ordenMatriz2;
    int matriz1[orden][orden];
    int matriz2[orden][orden];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < orden; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < orden; j++) {
            matriz1[i][j] = 1;
            matriz2[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }

    do {
        cX = 0; cY = 0;
        coordenadaX = sendcoordenadaxtoclient_1((void*)&sendcoordenadaxtoclient_1_arg, clnt);
        if (coordenadaX == (int *) NULL) {
            clnt_perror (clnt, "call failed");
        }
        coordenadaY = sendcoordenadaytoclient_1((void*)&sendcoordenadaytoclient_1_arg, clnt);
        if (coordenadaY == (int *) NULL) {
            clnt_perror (clnt, "call failed");
        }
        cX = coordenadaX;
        cY = coordenadaY;

        printf("\nCoordenadas obtenidas del server:\nX: %d\nY: %d", cX, cY);

        for (int i = 0; i < orden; i++) {
            putresultadomatrizresultante_1_arg.producto += matriz1[cX][i]*matriz2[i][cY];
        }

        printf("\nResultado a enviar al server:  %d", putresultadomatrizresultante_1_arg.producto);

        result_6 = putresultadomatrizresultante_1(&putresultadomatrizresultante_1_arg, clnt);
        if (result_6 == (void *) NULL) {
            clnt_perror (clnt, "call failed");
        }
    }while (coordenadaX != -1 && coordenadaY != 1);
    
#ifndef DEBUG
    clnt_destroy (clnt);
#endif   /* DEBUG */
}


int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *host;

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf ("usage: %s server_host\n", argv[0]);
        exit (1);
    }
    host = argv[1];
    matrizprograma_1 (host);
exit (0);
}
```

SERVER:

```
#include "Matriz.h"
//Variables globales para nuestro server
static int indicadorClientes = 0;
static int ordenMatriz = 0;
static int coordenadaX = 0;
static int coordenadaY = 0;
int *
checkoutclientesexistentes_1_svc(void *argp, struct svc_req *rqstp)
{
    static int  result;

    printf("\nNUEVO CLIENTE\n");

    if (indicadorClientes == 0) {
        printf("\nEs el primer cliente\n");
        result = indicadorClientes;
        printf("Se enviara la siguiente respuesta: %d\n", result);
        indicadorClientes = 1;
    } else {
        result = indicadorClientes;
        printf("\nYa existe otro cliente: %d\n", result);
    }

    return &result;
}

int *
setordenmatriz_1_svc(Orden *argp, struct svc_req *rqstp)
{
    static int  result;
    ordenMatriz = argp->ordenMatriz;
    result = argp->ordenMatriz; 
    return &result;
}

int *
getordenmatriz_1_svc(void *argp, struct svc_req *rqstp)
{
    static int  result;
    result = ordenMatriz;
    return &result;
}

int *
sendcoordenadaxtoclient_1_svc(void *argp, struct svc_req *rqstp)
{
    static int  result;
    result = coordenadaX;
    return &result;
}

int *
sendcoordenadaytoclient_1_svc(void *argp, struct svc_req *rqstp)
{
    static int  result;
    result = coordenadaY;
    return &result;
}

void *
putresultadomatrizresultante_1_svc(Producto *argp, struct svc_req *rqstp)
{
    static char * result;
    int resultado = 0;
    static int **matrizResultante;

    matrizResultante = (int *)malloc(ordenMatriz * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < ordenMatriz; i++) {
        matrizResultante = (int *)malloc(ordenMatriz * sizeof(int));
    }

    if(coordenadaX == -1 && coordenadaY == -1) {
        printf("\nMATRIZ RESULTANTE COMPLETADA");
        exit(1);
    }

    else if (coordenadaX != 5) {
        if (coordenadaY != 5) {
            resultado = argp->producto;
            matrizResultante[coordenadaX][coordenadaY] = resultado;
            coordenadaY++;
        } else if (coordenadaY == 5) {
            coordenadaX++;
            coordenadaY = 0;
        }
    } else if (coordenadaX == 5) {
        printf("\nMATRIZ RESULTANTE COMPLETADA\n");
        printf("Imprimiendo matriz:\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < ordenMatriz; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ordenMatriz; j++) {
                printf("%d, ", matrizResultante[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");           
        }
    }

    return (void *) &result;
}
```

ACTUALIZACION:
Ya pude resolverlo, mi problema era como usaba los punteros, muchisimas gracias a Mateo por tu grandisima ayuda y observaciones c: c:

Comment: Algunas observaciones: Cualquier puntero tiene conversión implícita al tipo `void *`. Por lo que no es necesario que hagas una conversión explícita `(void *)`. NULL es una constante que indica un puntero nulo y no hace falta que lo conviertas a (int *) por ejemplo. Y en un if con la condición `indicador == 0`. ¿No será que querías ver si el puntero apunta a una dirección que almacena un 0? En ese caso sería `*indicador == 0`.

Comment: @Mateo, de hecho esa conversion la genera en automatico cuando realizo el rpcgen del archivo .x, y en el caso del puntero y el If tienes razon, modifico eso, gracias  c:

Comment: @Mateo muchas gracias, ya vi cual era mi error gracias a tu observacion con lo de los punteros, muchas gracias c: c:

Comment: De nada. Crea una respuesta para tu propia pregunta entonces, así ayudarás a otras personas que se encuentren con un problema similar al tuyo.

Answer (score 0):

La solucion fue mi mal uso de punteros al igualarlos con variables que utilizaba en el cliente, por ejemplo, igualaba una variable con un puntero de la siguiente manera:

```
int *puntero = 0;
int variable;
variable = puntero;
```

mandando error de violacion de segmento, cuando la forma correcta era de la siguiente manera:

```
int *puntero = 0;
int variable;
variable = *puntero;
```